# How to cancel multitouch events?

Tags: macos, cocoa, touch, nsevent

We have an OS X application in which we need to block the pop-up dictionary that appears in response to a three-finger-tap.

Originally we looked into changing the values affected by the trackpad preference panel, but whatever uses these values doesn't pick up the changed value. Only the preference panel seems to affect anything. The commands we tried are:

```
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadThreeFingerTapGesture -int 0
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad TrackpadThreeFingerTapGesture -int 0
defaults write -g com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerTapGesture -int 0
defaults -currentHost write -g com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerTapGesture -int 0
```

If you log off and back in, then the settings will take effect. This is not an options for us.

The next thought was to override the three-figure-touch event in our application's main view. I can receive the events, but I don't see any to cancel the event. For example:

```
- (void)touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
  NSSet *touches = [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseTouching inView:nil];
  if(3 == [touches count]) {
    // Okay, now what?
  }
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Does simply overriding that method not block the look-up gesture?

Comment: Unfortunately not. On a whim I used `class_addMethod` to add my handler to the `NSView` superclass. I'm able to log all touch events to any view in my application, but it doesn't prevent any of them from occurring. Good thought though!